# AWS Toolkit Visual Studio Code Mac Unable to locate credentials

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, amazon-dynamodb, credentials, aws-toolkit

I successfully installed aws toolkit in my visual studio code.
I set all the credentials with region and the file is at .aws.
In Visual Studio the aws explorer shows my profile.

But when i try to run the following code:

```
import boto3 
import pprint as pp

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

table_name = 'Test_Dynamo' 

pk = 'U-0001'
stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE pk=? and begins_with(sk,'#U')" 
pmt =[{ "S": pk }] 

resp = dynamodb_client.execute_statement( Statement=stmt , Parameters= pmt ) 

pp.pprint(resp['Items'])
```

I get the following Error

```
Unable to locate credentials
```

I was expecting to fetch a Item from the DynamoDB.

Im running the code in the jupyter notebook extension of Visual Studio Code and my aws account is a free tier, if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying you set all the credentials with region.
As far as i know, the credentials are stored in a credentials file and the region is stored in a config file. Maybe it has something to do with that, that you probably put both in the same file which causes problems, can you check?

Comment: I tried it and it works. Problem was really that i didn't hat the config file with the region inside. Thx a lot